# Accessing all wall posts using RestFB

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm trying to access all posts on my wall using RestFB but for some reason all of my friends' posts in a certain time frame are collapsing into one "story". To make sense of what's happening, I tried querying my feed from Graph Explorer and here's what I saw:

```
"data": [
{
  "story": "ABC and 2 others wrote on your Timeline.",
  "created_time": "2016-05-16T10:41:02+0000",
  "id": "137024370031572_17180606569835"
},
{
  "story": "XYZ wrote on your Timeline.",
  "created_time": "2016-04-16T23:59:10+0000",
  "id": "137024370031572_137091220024887"
},
{
  "message": "Hello, World!",
  "created_time": "2016-04-16T23:58:25+0000",
  "id": "137024370031572_137090520024957"
}, 
{
  "message": "Hey!",
  "created_time": "2016-04-16T23:12:50+0000",
  "id": "137024370031572_137049793362363"
},
{
  "message": "Yo",
  "created_time": "2016-04-16T23:05:39+0000",
  "id": "137024370031572_137040810029928"
}
```

]

The posts that I made on my own wall show up as individual "messages" but all my friends' posts collectively appear as one story and if I try to print them out, I only see the most recent one and its message is null. Here's my code and the output I see on terminal:

```
Connection<Post> myFeed = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/feed", Post.class);
    for (List<Post> feed: myFeed) {
        for (Post post: feed) {
                System.out.println(post.getFrom().getName());
                System.out.println(post.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
ABC
null
XYZ
null
<My Name>
Hello, World!
<My Name>
Hey!
<My Name>
Yo
```

Anybody have any idea as to what I am doing wrong? Or how I can make this work? My user data permissions include publish_actions, user_friends and user_posts.

Comment: Already tried to fetch the id of the first element directly. Should be the 137024370031572_17180606569835. Would be interesting how this looks like. Otherwise this may be a bug ...

Comment: Tried accessing the first "story" element using its post id to see what happens -> still only get ABC and null. Is that what you meant for me to do?

Comment: I searched my feed and found a post that is similar to yours. Requesting the post directly via id results in an error. I think Facebook should provide a way to access the underlying posts to know how this story was created. But I have atm no idea how this can be done. So perhaps some one has a good idea or we nee to send Facebook a RFE/bug.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: No, I asked this on Facebook's Developer Forum and this is what they said: "This behavior is by design, and the API is working as expected.
I would also like to take this opportunity to remind you of our Platform Policy, which disallows auto-posting: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/"